# How to make sure user input text doesn't have bad characters using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation

Is there a way to make sure a large text (coming from a textarea) does not have bad characters, before sending that text by AJAX to a PHP file (which saves it to a database)?

I mean, prevent user to write an `<script></script>` or other dangerous words in textarea? Using JavaScript (not PHP)?

I validate the text in PHP, before sending it to database, I just want to validate the text also in JavaScript, before sending it to PHP.

Comment: You might not want to do your validation client side (only). It would be better to validate it with PHP. Someone can still send you bad data; they could just use `wget` or `curl` or Postman.

Comment: Also, what does "bad characters" mean? HTML entities? If so, you should not reject them, but just escape them.

Comment: in short - no, there is no way. :)

Comment: I mean I dont want to user to enter this :
<script></script>

Comment: @andy, you can use regex, replace... but, really - leave it to php, to do its job. :)

Comment: So , if validate the text in pho , its enough ?
there isnt any way for user to do some dirty thing using javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
'<bad></html>'.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```